# Use of find in foreach in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, foreach, find

Hey I am working in kotlin. I make a solution for my work. But I am little bit confused that about my approach is efficient or not. I am thinking is that my approach is for speed, memory and proper optimize solution or not? Can someone guide me

```
val listOne = listOf<Int>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
val listTwo = listOf(4, 7, 9, 10, 12, 15, 18)
fun main() {
    val secondList = mutableListOf<Second>()
    listOne.forEachIndexed { index, value ->
        val present = listTwo.find {
            value == it
        }
        secondList.add(
            Second(
                index,
                present != null
            )
        )
    }

    secondList.forEach { println(it) }
}

data class Second(
    val value: Int,
    val present: Boolean = false
)
```

I have two list `listOne`, `listTwo`. `listOne` is main list I want to find the value of present in `listTwo` and add into new `secondList`. Is there any better approach for this?

Comment: Performance optimization: make `listTwo` a set, it will have a better performance for lookup operation on it. Readability optimization: actually it all could be a one-liner: `val secondList = listOne.map { Second(it, it in listTwo) }`

Comment: @МихаилНафталь thanks for replying what is `it in listTwo` ? Can you please explain me in detail

Comment: See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#in-operator and https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this code is not optimal for the performence. But the fix is actually very easy - just change the type of the data structure you use.

The problem is that lists are not optimized for searching. For each item from `listOne` we have to iterate over elements in `listTwo`. As a result, the time complexity is `O(N*M)` where `N` and `M` are sizes of `listOne` and `listTwo` accordingly. We can replace/convert `listTwo` with a set. Sets are good for searching, they search in constant time, so the resulting time complexity is just `O(N+M)`. `M` for preparing a set and `N` for iterating over `listOne` and searching.

Additionally, your code can be greatly simplified by using `mapIndexed()` and replacing `find()` with simple `in`:

```kotlin
val s = listTwo.toSet()
val secondList = listOne.mapIndexed { index, item ->
    Second(index, item in s)
}
```

You can also create a set directly, using `setOf()` instead of `listOf()`.

Comment: thanks a million..

Comment: one question what is the use of `item in s` ? `in` means ?

Comment: It checks if the `item` exists in `s`/`listTwo`. It's an equivalent of your `find()` followed by comparing to null.

Comment: great thanks. What is d/w `forEachIndexed` and `mapIndexed` ?